# Parsing large amount of dates with pandas - scalability - performance drops faster than linear

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, scalability

I am facing a strange performance issue when parsing a lot of dates with Pandas 0.17.1. For demonstration, I created CSV files with exactly one column, containing datetimes in the format "2015-12-31 13:01:01". The sample files contain 10k, 100k, 1M, and 10M records. I am parsing it like this:

```
start = timer()
pd.read_csv('10k_records.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

The elapsed times are: 
10k: 0.011 s 
100k: 0.10 s 
1m: 1.2 s 
**10m: 300 s**

You see, the time scales linearly to the number of records until 1 million, but then there is a huge drop.

It's not a memory issue. I have 16GB, and I work with dataframes of this size without any problems in Pandas, only parsing of dates appears to be slow.

I tried to use *infer_datetime_format=True*, but the speed was similar. Also a huge drop for 10m records.

Then I tried to register my own naive date parser:

```
def parseDate(t):
    if type(t) is str :
        st = str(t)
        try:
          return datetime.datetime(int(st[:4]),int(st[5:7]),int(st[8:10]),int(st[11:13]),int(st[14:16]),int(st[17:19]))
        except:
          return None
    return datetime.datetime(0,0,0,0,0,0)

pd.read_csv(
    '10k_records.csv', parse_dates=['date'],
    date_parser=parseDate
)
```

And the times are now: 
10k: 0.045 s  
100k: 0.36 s 
1m: 3.7 s 
**10m: 36 s**

The routine is slower than the default pandas parser on smaller files, but it scales perfectly linearly for the larger one. So it really looks like some kind of performance leak in the standard date parsing routine.

Well, I could use my parser, but it's very simple, stupid, and apparently slow. I would prefer to use the intelligent, robust, and fast Pandas parser, only if I could somehow solve the scalability issue. Would anyone have any idea, if it could be solved, possibly by some esoteric parameter or something?

#### UPDATE

Thank all of you for your help so far.

After all, it seems that there is a reproduceable performance problem with dates parsing, but it has nothing to do with scalability. I was wrong in my original analysis.

You can try to download this file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5m21s1uif329f1/slow.csv.tar.gz?dl=0
and parse it in Pandas. The format and everything is correct, all the data are valid. There are only 100k records, but it takes 3 seconds to parse them - while it takes 0.1s to parse 100k records from the generated regular sequence.

What happened: I did not generate my original testing data as a regular sequence, as @exp1orer did. I was taking samples of our real data, and their distribution is not that regular. The sequence is overall growing by a constant pace, but there are some local irregularities and unordered pieces. And, apparently, in my 10M sample, there happened to be one section, which made pandas particularly unhappy and parsing took so long. It's only a tiny fraction of the file content that is responsible for all the slowness. But I was not able to spot any principal differences between that fraction and the rest of the file.

#### UPDATE 2

So, the cause of slowness was that there were some weird dates, like **20124-10-20**. Apparently, I will need to do some more pre-processing before importing the data to Pandas.

Comment: This is really interesting and a very well-defined question. Would you mind posting the code to generate the csv files as well?

Comment: I generate it from Java, if you do not mind. I will post it.

Comment: @exp1orer it's there, it just took me a couple of minutes to make it portable - to remove references to our proprietary stuff.

Comment: Heh, I ended up doing it myself in python. But I'm actually unable to reproduce your problem -- I also get about 1s for 1 million, but I get ~11s for 10 million, which is still linear. Here's what I'm doing: http://pastebin.com/92NaTgxn

Comment: I am using pandas '0.17.1'. What version do you have?

Comment: Hm, I tried it on 14.1 and 15.2. Let me try a higher version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108562/discussion-between-exp1orer-and-jan-x-marek).

Comment: Have you tried changing the test data to just repeat the same line over and over, to see whether the problem has anything to do with the data?

Comment: @user2357112 it has to do something with the data. It works fine on the data generated by exp1orer's routine, but misbehaves on my data. There will be some subtle difference, I do not know, line endings, quoting, something. I am examining it and will update the post as soon as I find it.

Comment: It looks to me like your Java code is going to hit integer overflow, since `i` is an `int` rather than a `long`. That probably has something to do with the problem.

Comment: It does not, because the start variable in the expression is long. But anyway, I will remove the java code, it only brings more confusion. It is not the exact code that I used to generate my testing data where I experienced the problem. It is simplified, with some external dependencies removed.

Comment: The `start` variable may be a long, but the `i * 1000` in `start + i * 1000` is purely an int operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

look at this comparison:

```
In [507]: fn
Out[507]: 'D:\\download\\slow.csv.tar.gz'

In [508]: fn2
Out[508]: 'D:\\download\\slow_filtered.csv.gz'

In [509]: %timeit df = pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['from'], index_col=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 15.7 s per loop

In [510]: %timeit df2 = pd.read_csv(fn2, parse_dates=['from'], index_col=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 399 ms per loop

In [511]: len(df)
Out[511]: 99831

In [512]: len(df2)
Out[512]: 99831

In [513]: df.dtypes
Out[513]:
from    object
dtype: object

In [514]: df2.dtypes
Out[514]:
from    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

The only difference between those two DFs is in the row# 36867, which i've manually corrected in the `D:\\download\\slow_filtered.csv.gz` file:

```
In [518]: df.iloc[36867]
Out[518]:
from    20124-10-20 10:12:00
Name: 36867, dtype: object

In [519]: df2.iloc[36867]
Out[519]:
from   2014-10-20 10:12:00
Name: 36867, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Conclusion**: it took Pandas 39 times longer because of one row with a "bad" date and at the end Pandas left `from` column in the `df` DF as a string

**OLD answer:**

it works pretty fair for me (pandas 0.18.0):

setup:

```
start_ts = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'

pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start_ts, freq='1S', periods=10**4)}).to_csv('d:/temp/10k.csv', index=False)

pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start_ts, freq='1S', periods=10**5)}).to_csv('d:/temp/100k.csv', index=False)

pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start_ts, freq='1S', periods=10**6)}).to_csv('d:/temp/1m.csv', index=False)

pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start_ts, freq='1S', periods=10**7)}).to_csv('d:/temp/10m.csv', index=False)

dt_parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

checks:

```
In [360]: fn = 'd:/temp/10m.csv'

In [361]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['date'], dtype={0: pd.datetime}, date_parser=dt_parser)
1 loop, best of 3: 22.6 s per loop

In [362]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['date'], dtype={0: pd.datetime})
1 loop, best of 3: 29.9 s per loop

In [363]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['date'])
1 loop, best of 3: 29.9 s per loop

In [364]: fn = 'd:/temp/1m.csv'

In [365]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['date'], dtype={0: pd.datetime}, date_parser=dt_parser)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.32 s per loop

In [366]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['date'], dtype={0: pd.datetime})
1 loop, best of 3: 3.06 s per loop

In [367]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['date'])
1 loop, best of 3: 3.06 s per loop

In [368]: %timeit pd.read_csv(fn)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.53 s per loop
```

conclusion: it's a bit faster when i'm using `date_parser` where i'm specifying the date format, so `read_csv` don't have to guess it. The difference is approx. 30%

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that you aren't able to reproduce either, right?

Comment: @exp1orer, yes, it's pretty linear for me

Comment: Cool. I tried on 18.0 as well and got it to be linear as well.

Comment: So, there actually seems to be a performance problem - see my update - but a different one than I originally thought.

Comment: @JanXMarek, i'm not sure, but it could be caused by bad dates, like this row: `36867,20124-10-20 10:12:00`

Comment: Indeed, the weird date seems to be slowing the parser down. Very well spotted, thanks. It seems I need to do some cleanup and pre-processing before importing the data to Pandas.

Comment: Why doesn't read_csv fails with some error message while parsing such weird dates?

Comment: @shantanuo, it does if you use `date_parser` argument

Answer (score 1):

Okay -- based on the discussion in the comments and in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108562/discussion-between-exp1orer-and-jan-x-marek) it seems that there is a problem with OP's data. Using the code below he is unable to reproduce his own error:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from time import time

format_string = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
base_dt = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
exponent_range = range(2,8)


def dump(number_records):
    print 'now dumping %s records' % number_records
    dts = pd.date_range(base_dt,periods=number_records,freq='1s')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [dt.strftime(format_string) for dt in dts]})
    df.to_csv('%s_records.csv' % number_records)


def test(number_records):
    start = time()
    pd.read_csv('%s_records.csv' % number_records, parse_dates=['date'])
    end = time()
    print str(number_records), str(end - start)

def main():
    for i in exponent_range:
        number_records = 10**i
        dump(number_records)
        test(number_records)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```